# Where does parameter value that not show in firefox dev edition go?

Tags: firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

where does firefox developer edition hide the XHR request param... ?

Here the image when i open the console tools and make some XHR request but none of parameter is show. Im using POST method when XHR it...

[image]

I am using firefox-dev edition version : 57.0b11 (64-bit)

thanks u for any guide.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately those litte guys comeback again to their home as this is getting solved in the newer version of firefox dev edition (58.0b4 (64-bit)

Thanks you