# Firefox uprade issue

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-quantum

My Firefox just upgraded itself to Firefox Quantum and now when I develop I can't seem to be able to find where are the parameters of the form that I POST. Anyone had this issue yet?

Comment: See [Where does parameter value that not show in firefox dev edition go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46923546/3367974)

Comment: Under the request parameters, it appears to only show the query string of the post URL, not the post body.

Comment: The title of your question doesn't express the issue you have. You should change it to make it more expressive. (Also, it includes a typo.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the information under the "console" tab is not consistent and confusing - it appears to only show query string parameters if they exist in the POST url.

However, under the "Network" tab, when you select the POST request, you can see the post body on the right under the "Params" tab.

Comment: FF used to show it and now I can see in Chrome only. FF messed this up.